# Looking for Tables of Chebyshev I Lumped Filters, for Various Ripple values (in dB)

Tags: filter, design, passive-networks

I have tables of Chebyshev I filter design only for 0.5dB ripple. I need the tables for other ripples. I can't find them on the internet. Could anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anatol Zverev : Handbook of Filter Synthesis.

Comment: Download LTSpice (free) and simulate them to get as many possibilities as your mind can come up with.

Comment: Why not use a program like Octave or [Python + SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cheby1.html) to compute the values for other ripples?

Comment: I am sure you can find the required tables via Google.

Comment: I found tables only for ripples of 0.1dB and 1dB here: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~Gerard.Borg/engn4545_borg/filters/filters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a table, but it might help you. There is a free RF filter design program at http://iowahills.com/9RFFiltersPage.html  You can get the Chebyshev values you want from the program by doing the following.

Since the lowest frequency allowed by the program is 1 kHz, set the design frequency to 1/(2*Pi) MHz = 0.159155 MHz. Then enter 1 Ohm for both the load and source impedance.

The program will give you the element values you want, but you will need to scale them by 1.0E6.

Another good book that shows how to calculate these values is "The Analysis, Design, and Synthesis of Electrical Filters" by Humpherys, 1970. See page 403.

Here are the equations given by Humpherys. As you can see, these calculations are not trivial. This is a screen shot from MathCad.

[image: Chebyshev Low Pass Element Equations]

Comment: Thank you for this. This seems to be almost what i wanted. Finally someone who is using Mathcad, which is a very good and very easy software.

Comment: BTW, you didn't say what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to get a Chebyshev response from a high frequency LC filter, you are most likely wasting your time. It isn't likely you can get components with the Q and precision needed to achieve the response you seeking.

Comment: I wanted to design a filter with Chebyshev responce, using LC lumped components and i wanted to have flexibility in choosing the ripple dB. For this i wanted Chebyshev tables of various ripples and i only had table for 0.5dB ripple.

Comment: You are doing what every RF engineer in the world has tried to do at one time or another, and we all failed. Simulate your circuit using real component values, especially Q, to see the problem.